# Angular controller Function not defined

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have tried creating a controller using `meanjs.org`. The controller is working fine with the other existing controllers but it is not working fine with new one I have created, Help would be appreciated, Thank you.

> angular.js:12808 Error: [ng:areq] Argument
>   'TestownerControllerController' is not a function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/ng/areq?p0=TestownerControllerController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

this is my controller code

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('users').controller('TestownerControllerController', TestownerControllerController);

  TestownerControllerController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function TestownerControllerController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    // Testowner controller controller logic
    // ...

    init();

    function init() {
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Share your code

Comment: I have created that using yo generator in meanjs.org, existing controllers are working fine, but new controller is not working

Comment: @vishuminhas please check I have shared the code

Comment: Quick response would be appreciated greatly

Comment: `use strict` prevents you from using functions before they are declared. Change the order and put the `TestownerControllerController`-function above the other two lines (which are trying to use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you miss `[]` where you define user app `angular.module('users')...`

`[]`: it's required and we use it to inject other modules.

also you can set a config in your app like this:

```
app.config(["$controllerProvider", "$compileProvider", "$filterProvider", "$provide", function ($stateProvider, configs, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {
app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
app.directive = $compileProvider.register;
app.filter = $filterProvider.register;
app.factory = $provide.factory;
app.service = $provide.service;
app.constant = $provide.constant;
}]);
```

This config help you to register a module with others dependencies.

```
//our main app
var app = angular.module('users', [])

//our controller
function testController($scope) {
    function init() {
        //somthing
    }
    init();
}

testController.$inject = ['$scope'];
app.controller('testController', testController);
```